# Best way to filter().update() in django while handling zero rows?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Is there a good way to filter().update() in django while handling zero rows? Lets say I want to run:

```
Dogs.objects.filter(noise='woof').update(animal_name='dog')
```

This throws and error if Dogs.objects.filter(noise=‘woof’) returns zero results. Now I can do:

```
dogs = Dogs.objects.filter(noise='woof')
if len(dogs) > 0:
    dogs.update(animal_name='dog')
```

But is just seems a bit messy, any better ways to do this? Something like:

```
Dogs.objects.filter(noise='woof').update_if_rows(animal_name='dog')
```

Comment: the most pythonic way to do it is to use a `try/except` block.

Comment: It will not throw any error, It will just return integer `0`, which means 0 rows updated and this is the accepted behavior. you don't have to handle it explicitly.

Comment: If you are getting any error or exception, update it to question, It must be something else

Comment: Add complete error message/stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are worried about `Dogs.objects.filter().update()` It would not raise Exception.

**This is a sql debug code** to see how  `filter().update()` is converted to raw sql query

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())    

Dogs.objects.filter(noise='woof').update(animal_name='dog')
```

**This is the sql query debug Result** sql query is very simple!. don't worry about zero rows.

```
UPDATE `app_dogs` SET `animal_name` = 'dog' WHERE `app_dogs`.`noise` = 'woof'
```

---

But If you still want exception handling

**A simple way**, in my opinion, is to use exception handling like this.

```
try:
    Dogs.objects.filter(noise='woof').update(animal_name='dog')
except DoesNotExist as e:
    pass
```

Comment: Nothing in that try block in the last example will raise a `DoesNotExist` exception. Those only get raised for 'get' operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
if dogs.exists():
   dogs.update(animal_name='dog')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with calling update even if there are no rows.

In fact, it's more efficient to do that rather than checking first because you'll be doing less queries.

Lets compare some of the options we have here;

```
Dogs.objects.filter(noise="woof").update(animal_name="dog")
```

This will do a single query that looks something like this.

```
UPDATE dogs SET animal_name = "dog" WHERE noise = "woof";
```

---

Now on to one of the simple examples in some of the answers;

```
dogs = Dogs.objects.filter(noise="woof")
if dogs.exists():
    dogs.update(animal_name='dog')
```

This will do a query to check to see if any dogs exist, followed by the update (if required).

```
SELECT 1 FROM dogs WHERE noise = "woof" LIMIT 1;
UPDATE dogs SET animal_name = "dog" WHERE noise = "woof";
```

Note that the final query is exactly the same as the only query we did above. We've done an extra round trip for no real gain here.

---

Now, the worst option of the lot.

```
dogs = Dogs.objects.filter(noise="woof")
if len(dogs):  # or len(dogs) > 0 or even just dogs - they all have the same effect
    dogs.update(animal_name="dog")
```

This will load the entire result set (that is, every animal in this table that makes a 'woof' noise) into Django. Then it will run the same query as per the last two examples.

```
SELECT * FROM dog WHERE noise="woof";
UPDATE dogs SET animal_name = "dog" WHERE noise = "woof";
```

This not only incurs the performance loss of making two round trips to our database server as per the previous example, but also exchanges quite a lot of data we throw away without even using. This option is painfully slow on larger tables - and in some cases you may run out of memory before it completes.

---

In conclusion - there is no need to check at all for entries in the table, as update handles them correctly whether they exist or not.

If you have logic that requires you to know whether or not anything got updated - use the return from update instead. It will give you the number of rows that were affected by this query.